# AngularJS + ChartJS not showing tooltips

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I have a directive, which is wrapped JQuery-library ChartJS. I have successfully used it in the component Menu:

```
Menu
  chart-js
```

By changing the architecture of the application, I began to use this directive (wrapped ChartJS) from another component - Charts. And Charts, in turn, has been used component Menu:

```
menu
  feed
  search
  charts
    chart-js
```

The problem - not always tultips displayed. Sometimes they are shown when i add more data. Sometimes, if i load a lot of data, etc. I can not find a pattern.

How do I resolve this problem?

**Update**

When i place сharts in div, tooltips dont work:

```
<div ng-show="$ctrl.showContentBlock">
    <charts></charts>
    <feed></feed>
</div>
```

If i place charts outside div, tooltips work:

```
<charts></charts>
<div ng-show="$ctrl.showContentBlock">
    <feed></feed>
</div>
```

Why is this happening?